# ServiceStack ServerEvents: send event from another process

Tags: servicestack

I have a need to send server-side events from another process which is performed at the time and I have no idea how to do it ))

I would be grateful for any help!

Thank you in advance!

```
public override void Configure(Container container) {
...
     container.Register(c => new DispatchService());
}

public class DispatchService {
.    
    public void SomeFunction(){
       //here I want to send an event to the session
       NotifySession(sspid, selector, message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved the problem as follows ))

```
container.Register(c => new DispatchService(Resolve<IServerEvents>()));

public class DispatchService {        
  public IServerEvents ServerEvents { get; set; }
  public DispatchService (IServerEvents ServerEvents) {       
      this.ServerEvents = ServerEvents;
  }
  public void SomeFunction(){       
      ServerEvents.NotifySession(sspid, selector, message);
  }
```